# WrapAll with NextUntil

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make sure all classes with `.px-sub-menu-item` are wrapped within a div?

```js
(function($) {
  $('.px-sub-menu-item').each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('.px-sub-menu-item').addBack('.px-sub-menu-item').wrapAll('<div class="px-menu-wrap"></div>');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <a href="#" class="px-main-menu-item">Home</a><br>
  <a href="#" class="px-sub-menu-item">Submenu 1</a><br>
  <a href="#" class="px-main-menu-item">Home 2</a><br>
  <a href="#" class="px-sub-menu-item">Submenu 2</a><br>
  <a href="#" class="px-sub-menu-item">Submenu 3</a><br>
  <a href="#" class="px-main-menu-item">Home 3</a><br>
</nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kqzj1tex/

Comment: Can you show the exact HTML structure you wish to convert your HTML to?

Comment: You'll have to be clearer, the elements have different classes and aren't siblings, how do you want them wrapped?

Comment: What's the output you expect from this?

Comment: And if this is supposed to be a nested navigation menu - then why is it not _output_ in a proper nested HTML structure to begin with, why do you have to “fix” this using JavaScript …?

Comment: I can't change the HTML structure, that's why I need to create a HTML structure with jQuery. All classes of the sub menu need to be wrapped together. If it's one sub menu, but also when there are multiple sub menu classes before the next main menu class. Basically I need to create a HTML structure of nav and subnav with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

`wrapAll` includes all selectors into **one** `div`. If you want to each `.px-sub-menu-item` wrap into separate div, you need to use `wrap` function.

```js
$('.px-sub-menu-item').wrap('<div></div>');
```

```css
div > .px-sub-menu-item{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>

<a href="#" class="px-main-menu-item">Home</a><br>
<a href="#" class="px-sub-menu-item">Submenu 1</a><br>
<a href="#" class="px-main-menu-item">Home 2</a><br>
<a href="#" class="px-sub-menu-item">Submenu 2</a><br>
<a href="#" class="px-sub-menu-item">Submenu 3</a><br>                      
<a href="#" class="px-main-menu-item">Home 3</a><br>

</nav>
```

Comment: You're assuming that the OP wants them all wrapped individually. The implication of `wrapAll()` is that they at least want siblings to share the wrapping element.

Comment: Indeed I want all sub menu classes that are before the next main menu class wrapped together.